# How to get draft mail instead of original one from Explorer Object

Tags: vba, outlook

When I reply to a mail i would get the Draft of the Reply from the Explorer object and not the Original mail with an expression like application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).xxxx .
The expression application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) give the original mail not the "reply Draft".

Thanks for answer

Desag

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2013 introduces a new property for the Explorer class – [ActiveInlineResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231535%28v=office.15%29.aspx). It allows getting an item which is listed in the Outlook 2013 reading pane in case the inline response is active.

For handling inline replies Outlook 2013 introduces a new event which notifies developers when the inline response is activated – the [InlineResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229061%28v=office.15%29.aspx) event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But i'd hope a more "elegant" solution because the draft mail isn't always in the reading pane; Nothing to "hook" the draft mailitem from the original one object?

Comment: How do you reply to the email? Do you click on the ribbon button?

Comment: In this case, yes, but it can be programatically and not just before i try to get the draft. I prefer something more general. For exemple, the mail in the reading pane isn't necessary the first in the selection (which I try to get the draft).